# How to detect failures in response to bulk operation?

Tags: elasticsearch, npm

I am using the `elasticsearch` npm library.

I use the bulk API to index documents:

```
const response = await this.elasticSearchClient.bulk({
     body: bulkRows,
});
```

It works.

But if ElasticSearch were to fail with some of the indexing, how can I detect those failures from the response?

I have found an example response in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) but I still don't understand how to detect failures:

Comment: hi can please tell how you using bulk request using in any programming language like java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by inspecting the response you get from the bulk call:

```
  const { body: bulkResponse } = await this.elasticSearchClient.bulk({ body: bulkRows })

  if (bulkResponse.errors) {
    const erroredDocuments = []

    bulkResponse.items.forEach((action, i) => {
      const operation = Object.keys(action)[0]
      if (action[operation].error) {
        erroredDocuments.push({
          // If the status is 429 it means that you can retry the document,
          // otherwise it's very likely a mapping error, and you should
          // fix the document before to try it again.

          status: action[operation].status,
          error: action[operation].error,
          operation: body[i * 2],
          document: body[i * 2 + 1]
        })
      }
    })

    console.log(erroredDocuments)
  }
```